# javascript open link in external program instead browser

Tags: javascript, onclick, crm, window.open, lotus

is there any way to use javascript to open a link in an external program and not(!) in the web browser?

Background: From CRM2015 on-premise i want to open a Mail in Lotus Notes.

script:

```html
<html>
<body>
<p onclick="myFunction()">Click me</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("notes:///server/file");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What happens: the mail opens in Lotus Notes -> good

But also an additional tab in IE11 occurs, blank page and link in address bar -> bad

What should happen: mail will open in Lotus Notes but no additional tab or windows in IE11.

Is there any way to solve my issue?

Thanks a lot for you help and have a great weekend!

Comment: Would `<a href="notes:///some/thing">a normal link</a>` work?

Comment: unfortunately not. it's a "ribbon button" and for supported changes javascript has to be used.

Comment: What I meant was "normally navigate to a link instead of opening a window." I believe `window.location` is the JS property you want to set.

Comment: Maybe something like: `var elem = \'<a id="test" href="notes://some/thing"></a>\'; $('body').append(elem); $('#test').click(); $('#test').remove();`

Comment: @Cyclone: Unless it needs to go through a `click` handler for some unknown reason (unlikely), that's a very Rube Goldberg solution. Let's see what becomes of `window.location="notes:///blah/foo";`

Comment: windows.location works on my local test html, let me test it in crm

Answer (score 2):

If you want to navigate to an external protocol via JS, do it the same way you'd navigate to a HTTP URL:

```
function goSomewhere() {
    window.location = "notes:///server/file";
}
```

Sane browsers should 1. stay on the same page, and 2. launch the external program (emphasis on *should* and no guarantees on insane browsers - e.g. IE8 and below).

Comment: I can sense years of pain of dealing with great mixrosoft products

Comment: @Yerken: Not specifically, and not recently. Some ancient browsers (Chrome around v2, FF 3.5, and all sorts of IE) used to launch the program, but put the page into an unresponsive state (navigated away without erasing the rendering), which used to lead to *interesting* behavior.